# iOS Storyboard switch views with differents tabbar

Tags: iphone, ios, storyboard, tabbar

I'm developing a iOS app. The App has two states: user is logged, user isn't logged.

If you init the app (user isn't logged) there are two tabs. Then if you want, you can log in and the app must show 4 tabs. If you close the app and start it again the app must shows the 4 tabs.

I use user preferences to store the credentials users to know if the user is logged or not, but how I can implement it?

How (using storyboards) I can show a tabbar with 4 tabs or 2 tabs?

And, how I can change the 2tabs tabbar to 4tabs tabbar when the app is executing (when you init the app and you aren't logged and you logs in)?

Thanks. Please, If you can give examples of code I'd appreciate it.

A solution:
You must create three storyboard. For example:

```
init.storyboard
logged.storyboard (with 4 tabs)
nologged.storyboard (with 2 tabs)
```

On init.storyboard you can start the storyboard you want

```
UIViewController *viewController;

if(user is logged)
  viewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Logged" bundle:NULL] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"init_tab"];
else
  viewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"NoLogged" bundle:NULL] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"init_tab"];

[self presentViewController:viewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Then, when you want to show the app with 4 tabs or 2 tabs, you should do the same "launch"

```
UIViewController *vc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Logged" bundle:NULL] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"init_tab"];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

this code is for a controller in nologged.storyboard

Check that I use a identifier "init_tab" on the storyboard, so ifyou want you can put a identifier on a view in each storyboard.

Comment: I have the solution. If someone want the solution, please write here. (The solution is large)

Comment: I would be interested in the solution - thanks in advance

Comment: I put my solution brainray

Answer (score 0):

I think this is easyer in your code, make everything normally in the story board. Put the 4 views atached to the tab bar.

Then depending in if user is logged or not hide or unihide method to show or not the 2 views programically...

Edit: in your viewdid load the 2 views should be view.hiden = YES;
Then in another method like when user is logged in make view.hiden = No;

Its just an idea to start with

Comment: The tabbar with 2 tabs shows the views A and B. The tabbar with 4 tabs shows the views A,C,D,E

Answer (score 0):

So you are going to want to modify the `viewControllers` property of the tab bar. You can either choose to add the two new view controllers once you get a notification saying the user is logged in, or have 4 by default and remove them if the user is not logged in. You can check in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` and then grab your tabBarController with `self.window.rootViewController`.

Comment: viewControllers is not mutable by default so you will have to create a mutable copy to add/remove items

Comment: mros, Yes. And you can't modify a tabbar linked a tabbarcontroller (i'm using storyboard and a tabbarcontroller)

Comment: So there is a method called setViewControllers:animated: on UITabBarController